# I don't know why it says 'preventing a complete tally of the injured'

Tags: grammar

> The wounded were taken to different hospitals around the city, which police said was preventing a complete tally of the injured.

Tally means count, right? In this sentence, the wounded were taken to different hospitals around the city, but why to prevent 'complete tally of the injured'?
This sentence comes from Fox News.

Comment: Because no one could keep track of which hospitals had how many wounded.  In a mass injury situation medical workers are focused on getting the injured to a place where they can be cared for.  Counting them is way down the priority list.

Comment: Tally means count. Yes. "…but why to prevent 'complete tally…" do you mean what is preventing the complete tally or why is there not a complete tally? In that event, there may not be a response from all possible sources.

Comment: You've asked "but why to prevent 'complete tally of the injured'?" Is this expressed poorly, or are you genuinely asking (as the wording suggests you are) why the police used the strategy of taking the wounded to different hospitalsd *in order to prevent* the possibility of a complete tally?

Comment: I‘m genuinely asking why police took the wounded to different hospitals to prevent a complete tally. Is that for preventing unnecessary guess by medias?’

Comment: The wounded were taken to different hospitals so as not to cause a backup at one hospital, with people waiting in the halls for attention or life-saving surgery.  The nearest hospitals, and/or the largest hospitals and/or the hospital(s)  with outstanding trauma units probably got most of the victims, but there was no plot on the part of the police to keep the information from reporters.

Comment: Yes, in a situation like this, with multiple injuries in a large city, injuries will be "triaged", with the most critical injuries being sent by ambulance to nearby trauma centers, and the less critically injured being sent to perhaps more distant hospitals, or ones that are not set up to treat severe trauma but which can handle cuts, abrasions, and the occasional broken bone.  Often these less critically injured would be transported in police cars or private vehicles.  Additionally, you may have people being treated and transported from several different locations, with no coordination.

Comment: The fact that a count was "prevented" does not mean that there was any conscious plan on the part of anyone to prevent the count.  It is simply the circumstances that prevent it.

Comment: How should I understand 'a complete tally'? From comments above, I can get the idea that the injured go to different hospitals according to their severity of injuries. But does 'a complete tally' mean 'complete count of the injured'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of different possibilities exceeds the amount of time available to make a verified account of the involved individuals and their specific circumstances. Dynamic conditions can make an accurate accounting time-dependant. By the time the information is reported by one person, it may have changed, making the existing report incorrect. Where data is in conflict, other time-sensitive information must be located and compared from an acceptable verifiable source. Multiply this situation by all the possible "hospitals" around the city and you get an idea of the complexity.

Also, who does the calling? Where does the call go? Who answers these calls? Who verifies the information? How often is the information updated?

The sheer complexity of assembling ***the*** unassailable true and stable answer makes a complete tally of the injured not possible for the convenience of the Fox News broadcast time by the police spokes-person designate is one very probable answer to why.